# How to open network icon in systray with PowerShell (not NCPA.cpl)

Tags: powershell, networking, systray

I'm searching for opening the network systray icon by powershell (left click), to show all of network avaliable connection. I've found of course about .cpl and NCPA, but not how I can open this systray popup programmatically.

There is also `netsh interface show interface` but it's in Command Line. Does I need to recreate an interface ?

Perhaps this panel is created "on-the-fly", that's why I can't open it externally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to open `Network Flyout`:

[image: Network FLyout]

This can be done two ways:

- Run `%windir%\explorer.exe shell:::{38A98528-6CBF-4CA9-8DC0-B1E1D10F7B1B}`
- Run `rundll32.exe %SystemRoot%\system32\van.dll,RunVAN`

Reference:

- [How to Create a "Networks" (Connect To) Shortcut in Windows 8 and 8.1](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/10190-networks-flyout-shortcut-create-windows-8-a.html)